For a matrix $A(z)$ that represents the operation of multiplication with a complex number $z$, what does it mean for $e^{A(z)t} = A(e^{zt})$?
We can have a complex number $z = a + bi$ that determines a matrix $A(z)$ in the following way:
$$ A(a + bi) = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} $$
This matrix represents the operation of multiplication by $z$, in the sense that if $z(x + yi) = v + wi$ then $A(z) \begin{bmatrix} x \ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v \ w \end{bmatrix}$.
I understand that numerically $e^{A(z)t} = A(e^{zt})$, but how is it that the matrix that shows the operation of multiplication with a complex exponential is equal to the matrix exponential of $A(z)$? Can someone explain the relation with an example?

You just need to know that $A(z + w) = A(z) + A(w), A(zw) = A(z) A(w)$ and that $A$ is continuous. It follows that $A$ sends power series to power series. Formally this is saying that $A$ is a homomorphism of Banach algebras.

Let’s write $z=re^{j\theta}$, then
$$A(z) = \begin{bmatrix}
r\cos(\theta) & -r\sin(\theta) \\
r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We can show by induction that
$$A^k(z) = A(z^k)$$
Assume $A^{k-1}(z) = A(z^{k-1})$. Then,
$$
A^k(z) = A^{k-1}(z) A(z)\\
 =\begin{bmatrix}
r^{k-1}\cos((k-1))\theta) & -r^{k-1}\sin((k-1)\theta) \\
r^{k-1} \sin((k-1) \theta) & r^{k-1}\cos((k-1)\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
r\cos(\theta) & -r\sin(\theta) \\
r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}\\
 =\begin{bmatrix}
r^k\cos(k\theta) & -r^k\sin(k\theta) \\
r^k\sin(k\theta) & r^k\cos(k\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now using the series expansion of $e^{A(z)t}$, we get
$$
e^{A(z)t} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k(z)t^k}{k!} =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A(z^k)t^k}{k!}
$$
Similarly, we can write the series expansion of $A(e^{zt})$ as
$$
A(e^{zt}) = A( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k t^k}{k!})  \\
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A(z^k)t^k}{k!} = e^{A(z)t}
$$
Here we have used the properties:

$A(z_1 + z_2) = A(z_1) + A(z_2)$. This implies that $A\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} z_i \right) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} A(z_i)$.
$A(cz) = cA(z)$ where $c$ is a real scalar.


You didn't just use those properties - there's a hidden assumption. When you move A through the infinite sum, it has to be justified.

How? The additive property lets me move A through the sum. What other assumption is there?

That's not correct - the additive property only lets you move it through finite sums. This one is infinite.
